# Maximising the profit using DP?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have an algorithmic problem. I tried solving, but couldn't get the solution. I know it can be solved using dp, but not quite getting the niche. A recursive dp using memoization algo would be ideal for me to understand. Even a small hint or link can do. The problem statement is:

"A shopkeeper has 'n' apples of weight a<sub>i</sub>. At any day he sells exactly one of the apples. But due to bacteria, the apples loose their weights and hence the shopkeeper earns a profit of a<sub>i</sub>%d (i.e., a<sub>i</sub> mod d) when he sell the apple of weight a<sub>i</sub> on day 'd'.
What is the maximum profit the shopkeeper can make"

Input:
The first line is 'n' and the second line contains weights of n apples.

Example:

Input:

2

3 4

Output:

1

Explanation: The shopkeeper sell the apple 4 on first day and the apple 3 on second day. Therefore profit = 4%1+3%2 = 1

Comment: The problem statement doesn't make much sense. The value of the apples doesn't decrease over time. 4%1=0, 4%2=0, 4%3=1, 4%4=0, 4%5=4, 4%6=4 ...

Comment: how many apples does the shopkeeper have?

Comment: The problem would make more sense if the shopkeeper earned a profit of a_i/d at the d-th day. Taking mod seems really weird.

Comment: @user172818 Just a hypothetical problem..no concerns..:)

Comment: In that case, Abhishek gives the right answer. I am not sure this problem can be solved by DP. It does not have the DP structure so far as I see.

Comment: I have a solution using dp, but it holds only for n < 20 (approx.). I actually use a bit masks and that mask integer as the index of the dp table...The masks keep count of which apples are sold..but I wanted a more general solution which would be valid for large n like 10<sup>3</sup>, but an easier approach (not involving graphs) (if any:)..

Comment: It seems that you have an exponential algorithm. Yes, you can do that kind of DP, but it is the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

This according to me can be solved using Maximum Weight Matching in a Bipartite Graph.

Shopkeeper has `n` apples and he has to assign each apple to a day from `1 to n`. He also knows the respective profits associated.

Hence a `nxn` complete bipartite graph can be formed and the maximum weight matching can be obtained using the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: you mean "maximum weighted bipartite matching"?